# Resolve url to .aspx on different DNN Pages

Tags: image, url, dotnetnuke

I create the following HTML code behind the scenes on the server side in a custom DNN Module. This must be done created on the server and not in a CSS.

```
<div class=""ca-icon"" style=""background-image: url(DesktopModules/MyModule/" +
                    "ShowPictureImg.aspx?Key=" + KeyImgList(itemCount - 1) + ")"">
```

To explain what your seeing, I'm pointing to a .aspx within my module that will load an image and place it as the background image for that div. I already know that this works. The problem occurs with the url linking to it. Based on if the module is placed on the parent page or within child pages the url will fail. The only way it works is like so:

Parent Page:

```
url(DesktopModules/MyModule/ShowPictureImg.aspx?Key=SomeKey)
```

Child of Parent:

```
url(../DesktopModules/MyModule/ShowPictureImg.aspx?Key=SomeKey)
```

Child of Child:

```
url(../../DesktopModules/MyModule/ShowPictureImg.aspx?Key=SomeKey)
```

And so on and so forth. How can I get a url that will work consistently regardless of where the module is placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that `ControlPath` worked in all cases as far as I could tell. So my final result for the url was something like this.

```
"url(" + ControlPath + "ShowPictureImg.aspx?Key=" + Key + ")"
```

This essentially resulted in `url(/site/DesktopModules/Modulename/ShowPictureImg.aspx?Key=1234)`

Answer (score 4):

If you are distributing this module to the wild, I would actually use ResolveClientUrl() to get the URL as /DesktopModules.. etc will not work if you are in a child portal setup, or if DNN is not in the root of the site.

Overall it would be something like

```
<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Desktop...") %>
```

WHere your full path was there with a ~/ at the beginning

This will ensure that it is processed properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `url(/DesktopModules/MyModule/` (notice the `/` at the beginning), it should start your URL at the root of your website. Assuming you are not running your website in a sub-directory this should work just fine for what you need.